# Tools for creating and managing a Data Dictionary

Tags: research-process, data, software, databases, lab-management

I'm looking for tools to create a data dictionary for my project's data.  We have a large database of many variables, and I would like to create a data dictionary that describes what each variable means so that I can share it with collaborators and other researchers (including on the [Open Science Framework](https://osf.io/)).  I'd like other researchers to be able to use the data dictionary to understand the data we have, find the variables they need, etc.  I'm not sure what tools/software/systems are available for this purpose, and whether I should just create a large spreadsheet to do this, or whether there are more specialized tools that people like for this purpose.

For a sense of what my data dictionary might include, here are suggested guidelines for what a data dictionary should include according to the Open Science Framework (https://help.osf.io/hc/en-us/articles/360019739054-How-to-Make-a-Data-Dictionary):

- Variable name
- Human-readable variable name
- Variable type (string, numeric, integer, etc.)
- Measurement unit
- Allowed values
- Definition and description of the variable

Comment: Note that "shopping questions" do not include recommendations for software solutions: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3658/17886. As noted here (https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4679/17886), "Softwarerecs.se is a bad idea for specialized needs". I posted my question here rather than on Softwarerecs.se because my question deals with a specialized need.

Comment: How is this question different from "How do I make a database?"

Comment: A data dictionary is a specialized database in academic research.  The needs will differ from other types of databases.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed some tools available for such 'metadata management'. You can find a list here: https://library.stanford.edu/research/data-management-services/data-best-practices/creating-metadata/metadata-tools

Answer (score 1):

I would keep things simple and write a small script in Python (or your preferred language) to read and write entries with the desired fields to a JSON file. You could also do .csv, but JSON is nice a readable. Then place the script alongside the database in a shared repository so that you can grant access to anyone who needs to query or edit the database, and you have version control too :).

Even if you do not have any programming experience, I would be surprised if you didn't have a collaborator who could help you set up such a thing.